# ith order statistic with bandwidth constraint

Tags: algorithm, array-algorithms

Consider the following: Mary and Larry each have an array, M [1,..., n] and
L[1,..., n] respectively. All of the elements in M and L are distinct. Mary and
Larry are interested in finding the i th order statistic of their combined arrays.
Because Mary and Larry live in different cities, they have communication
limitations in the way of bandwidth. They can send each other either one integer
at a time where the value either falls within {0,..., n} or any value drawn from the
M or L arrays. Each numeric transmission counts as a communication. You can
define your own protocol based on these constraints. One goal of this problem is
to minimize the number of communications needed to compute the combined
i th order statistic. Derive an algorithm minimizing the number of
communications.

I am having trouble coming up with an efficient way of finding the ith order statistic. I have been trying to use the Random-Select algorithm to recursively solve the problem, however the communication piece is throwing me off. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That sounds rather like a Median of medians (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) problem to me

Comment: Cute disguise on a somewhat well-known problem. Don't be shy about doing computation locally: it's free!

Comment: @DavidEisenstat - What do you mean by cute disguise? And I have been trying to make each do partitioning and send some piece of valid information back to the other, but I can't figure out what exactly they both need to know between partition calls.